# Analyse apex logs

Tags: apex, cpulimit, debug-logs

[image: Debug log Inspector]I am trying to analyse an apex log to find the operation taking maximum time. I am using log inspector.

1. Under Execution tree : Workflow:user duration is in negative ( -69,295) - **What does this negative number indicate**? Note - I haven't got the apex cpu limit error and the execution was successful.
2. Under Execution Overview , tab - Timeline has VALIDATION as the most contributed in overall execution (74.75% ) where as WORKFLOW contributed 0.24% .
   **Doesn't this contradict the duration in the execution tree which shows workflow as : -69,925.
   Shouldn't workflow contributed more than the validation in the execution time?**

Attaching the screenshot for the reference and clarity.

Comment: The negative duration displayed might be due to some defect in the log inspector. If you expand `Workflow:user` in the stack tree, do you see positive duration for anything in the tree structure? Considering point # 1 is caused by bug, I wouldn't jump into any conclusions about the values displayed in `Execution Overview` tab (seems fine to me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution tree subtracts times from each other to determine the entire execution time of each node. In some rare cases when the total tree has a large execution time but a specific node has a very small execution time, you can sometimes see absurd negative numbers.

This is because of a rounding error where small fractions of a millisecond accumulate a negative difference. I don't know what exactly triggers it, but I have seen it before. I'd recommend that you just ignore it, though, as it's clearly not the culprit (the timeline below shows 115ms for the workflow rules, which looks about right).

The big yellow bar for validation shows an actual time of 36 seconds, so this is clearly where the problem lies. You'll need to optimize whichever object is causing this problem. Reading the logs directly will tell you which rule or rules are causing the most impact.